# HTTPS forbidden on meta?

Tags: support

I often use a system that wants to block selective statements that I send out. Not sure why, but it's a work system, go figure... I've found that going to the site in HTTPS will prevent such filtering from occurring (I use my own devices so no custom root certificates installed). I tried to go to meta via HTTPS, and was told that it isn't allowed. Why is HTTPS allowed on the main site, but not on meta?

Comment: So your company is doing DPI... That's very intrusive.
More than a bug, I think this is a feature request.

Comment: It took me quite a while to realize what was happening myself...

Comment: HTTPS on meta is [not supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266711/1438) right now. Unfortunately, we can get a certification for `meta.*.stackexchange.com` and we don't relish the idea of maintaining hundreds of certifications for per-site metas. There is a plan, but it's not exactly a top priority at the moment.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/265918/155668 . Oh well, same site, but on meta.stackexchange... Sigh.

Comment: I have switched to the Emacs app for Stack Exchange. It works fine, and in fact I'm posting this comment via TLS API.

Answer (score 3):

I'm retagging this since the [main issue is tracked over on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/265918/accessing-per-site-metas-gives-403-forbidden-from-cloudflare-nginx).

The gist of the problem here is that to properly fix this, we need to change how meta URLs work. We do have a plan, but it's not a trivial change and we're having trouble finding the time while juggling all the other stuff. HTTP-everywhere-on-the-network is not abandoned, it just keeps losing the priority battle for the time being. Hopefully soon? But unfortunately I can't make any promises on the timeline here.